# Display an id from database column before the id is actually created

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, exception, frontend

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using HRMSController;
using HRMSBusinessEntities;
using System.Data;


namespace HumanResourceManagementSystems
{
    public partial class HRMSEmployee : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = (string)(Session["LoginUser"]);
            if (Session["LoginUser"] != null)
            {
                lblDisplay.Text = "Welcome..." + username;
            }
            Calendar1.Visible = false;
            Label1.Visible = false;
            txtcurrdate.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
        }

        protected void Btnmodified_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = true;

        }
        protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EmployeeEntity record = new EmployeeEntity
            {
                name = txtname.Text,
                currentdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtcurrdate.Text),
                modifieddate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtmodifieddate.Text)
            };
            EmployeeController add = new EmployeeController();
            add.Add(record);
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Added" ;
            Clear();


        }
        public void Clear()
        {
            txtname.Text = "";
            txtcurrdate.Text = "";
            txtmodifieddate.Text = "";
        }

        protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtmodifieddate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
        }

        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clear();
        }

        protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = true;
        }
    }


}
```

I have created a page for inserting Employee details in Visual studio 2010.When I click on Add,it displays as added and the id automatically gets increments in the back end.But instead of added,if I had to display as ("Your EMP ID is somenumber(eg.10) )in front end while execution,what should I do?

Comment: When I insert the employee details and when I click on the add button,it shouldnt display as added,instead it should display as Your Employee ID is 10(or some number).What is the code should I include for that in my already existing code? @David

Comment: Then I imagine you'd want to modify this line of code: `Label1.Text = "Added";`  Did you try anything at all?  If you want to change the text "Added" to something else then it seems *pretty obvious* where that would happen.

Comment: We made changes to the code,but it requires to display the Employee ID number along with the text  Example: Label1.Text = "Added" ===> Label1.Text = " Your employee id is " 10(it should display this number 10.But we dont know how to display @David

Comment: raghav, do you know what the actual Employee ID is, at the time of adding? Is it returned from calling the Add method in your EmployeeController?

Comment: No the Employee ID generates on its own.We have given identity to employee id in the backend sql server 2008. @LarsKristensen

Comment: @raghav: Take a look at `string.Format()`.  Or even just concatenating the strings directly.  Something as simple as: `Label1.Text = string.Format("Your employee ID is {0}.", theID);`  Just replace `theID` with whatever variable holds the employee ID at that time.

Comment: @raghav I hope it is obvious, that you can't display the ID, if you don't know what it is. Create a way to obtain the ID after creating the Employee, and then use the String.Format() approach that David has suggested.

Comment: How do I by creating a employee ID ? @LarsKristensen

Comment: @raghav, I can't determine that, from the code you have posted. Can you show what happens inside the "Add" method of you EmployeeController?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think displaying the employee id while the user is still creating the employee is a good idea.

Assume user1 is lingering in the page taking his time to create new employee, there might be some other user(user2) who is also trying to create an employee at the same time.User2 has created the employee while user1 still hasn't. So, showing the employee while creating will create ambiguity as there might be many other emplyees created by the time the current user creates his employee.

So may be it is better to display the employee id to the user in a label once he is done with creation of the employee.

```
label1.text="Employee succesfully added"+getemployeeid();

public string getemployeeid(){return yourobject.hitTheDataBaseMethod().tostring();};
```